# Anonymous function C++

Tags: c++, lambda, c++11, anonymous-function

I am trying to use the function `signal(int,void(*)(int))` from `<csignal>` to handle the floating point exception SIGFPE. I'd like to be able to print some useful diagnostics besides just a message saying "Floating point exception" or something to that effect. This means the function I pass as the handler to `signal` needs access to some of the data in my code. Therein lies the rub.

The function must return `void` and accept only 1 parameter of type `int`. I cannot make the handler a member function of my data storage class since then the type would be `void(Foo::*)(int)` due to the hidden `this` pointer.

I thought about using lambdas to try and make an anonymous function like this;

```
void handler(int nSig, Foo data)
{
    // do something
}
// snip
Foo data;
signal(SIGFPE, [&](int nSig)->void{handler(nSig,data);});
```

however because the lambda captures the variable `data` from outside the compiler will not let it be cast to a pointer to `void(*)(int)` (which is a shame as this seems like an ideal use for lambdas).

I could simply make `data` a global variable which could then be seen in `handler` but I am loath to do this for obvious reasons.

So my question is thus; **what is the best way of mimicking anonymous functions in C++**?

Note: I would prefer a native C++ solution and not to have to use boost or equivalent.

Comment: What do you mean you can't cast `data` to a `void(*)(int)`? `data` is an instance of `Foo`... Why can't you call `data.handler(nSig)`?

Comment: If I make `handler` a member of class `Foo` then it's function signature is now `void(Foo::*)(int)` not `void(*)(int)` the reason is that non-static member functions have a hidden pointer to the calling object (`this` is a hidden first argument) :-(

Comment: @Dave He meant he can’t cast the *lambda*.

Comment: Oh sorry, I can see how my wording could be misconstrued.

Comment: Can `signal` accept a `std::function<void(int)>` instead?

Comment: @Dave: It's a stupid C function. It just `call`s the given pointer with a single argument.

Comment: Note that there exists sigaction() and the flag SA_SIGINFO which might be a bit better suited for your needs of providing more information (which does however not change anything in the original part of the question)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no such thing as an anonymous function in C (C++ is irrelevant here, as the function must abide by the C calling convention).

The only thing you can do is *shiver* access globals from the handler, probably global *variables* (and not constants which would be fine).

I advise making those globals *thread local* to avoid multithreading issues, but it is still *bad* in the sense that global variables make for more brittle applications.

---

**How to ?**

*Note: as Luc Danton patiently explained to me, a signal may interrupt any non-atomic activity, and thus reading from a global is safe only if it is a lock-free atomic (or a few other things). **Unfortunately `std::function` may not be so, depending on your implementation**, I will still leave this code to explain how it could be done **providing that `std::function` accesses are atomic**.*

It is possible to create a trampoline that will call stateful stuff, isolating thread and allowing re-entrant calls.

```
typedef std::function<void(int)> SignalHandlerType;

extern thread_local ignalHandlerType SignalHandler;
```

And we create the following accessor (passed to signal):

```
void handle_signal(int const i) {
    if (SignalHandler) { SignalHandler(i); }
}
```

as well as the following RAII setter:

```
class SignalSetter: boost::noncopyable {
public:
    SignalSetter(int signal, SignalHandlerType&& sh):
        signal(signal), chandler(0), handler(sh)
    {
        chandler = std::signal(signal, &handle_signal<T>);
        swap(SignalHandler, handler);
    }

    ~SignalSetter() {
        std::signal(signal, chandler);
        swap(SignalHandler, handler);
    }

private:
    typedef void(*CHandlerType)(int);

    int signal;
    CHandlerType chandler;
    SignalHandlerType handler;
};
```

*Note: both the global variable and the `handle_signal` could be `private` to the `SignalSetter` class... but since `std::signal` is not...*

Expected usage:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    SignalSetter setter(SIGFPE, [argc, argv]() {
        std::cout << argc << ": " << argc << std::endl;
    });

    // do what you want.
}
```

Comment: I wouldn’t say that C++ is irrelevant, since, if C++ offered a shim from captures to function pointers, this would work. And note that while C++ does *not* offer such a way (for good technical reasons) it’s actually not impossible.

Comment: @Konrad: That's interesting. Do you have more information about the good technical reasons? I imagine this feature would need some kind of dynamically generated trampoline code

Comment: @NiklasB. Well, closures are implemented via functors – i.e. structures that overload `operator()`. You can get a pointer to that function, but that’s a *member function pointer* and incompatible with a normal function pointer. In order to get a normal function pointer you *need* a free function. You may consider that a trampoline (but a trampoline usually gets its callee passed as an argument, and that doesn’t work here since that would break the signature, you actually need a global object or something, just like Matthieu suggested).

Comment: @Konrad: Yeah, trampoline isn't the right word. You could probably generate a stub function with the proper signature dynamically and put it somewhere, but that would require memory that is both writable and executable, which is generally a very bad thing security-wise and probably not even possible on all platforms.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: Right, C++ could be relevant if it were able to synthesize a trampoline. I am too fan of self-modifying code so I would prefer the other possibility of a trampoline + thread-local reference to data, which is possible too, and with automatic generation could be made reentrant automatically as well. But it's not implemented either.

Comment: Hmm, shame. Is there a more C++ equivalent of `csignal` then?

Comment: @Dan: Not to the best of my knowledge. I implemented an example of how to use RAII and thread-local state *trampoline* rolled into one :D

Comment: Note that accessing global state from a signal handler is problematic (cf. type `std::sig_atomic_t`) if relying on the Standard guarantees only. Please clarify what makes your current solution work (typical implementation guarantees or the like).

Comment: @LucDanton: This is why it is important that the global state be local to the thread. The global variable `SignalHandler` is, it is up to the user to live up to that expectation for the state she passes.

Comment: @MatthieuM. I disagree. In the words of the Standard: "When the processing of the abstract machine is interrupted by receipt of a signal, the values of objects which are neither
— of type volatile std::sig_atomic_t nor
— lock-free atomic objects (29.4)
are unspecified during the execution of the signal handler, and the value of any object not in either of these two categories that is modified by the handler becomes undefined." Where does `thread_local` come into this?

Comment: @LucDanton: I am not basing myself on the Standard itself, but looking at [n2547](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2008/n2547.htm): **Allow atomics use in signal handlers**. Anything apart from `volatile std::sig_atomic_t` and lock-free atomic objects is implementation defined, however this is because signal handlers and locks do not interact conventionnally. My reasoning is thus that, in practice, avoiding multi-thread interactions on the variable touched should work. I offer no guarantee, mind.

Comment: @Matthieu I've never heard of a "trampoline" before but I think I understand what your code does :) Thanks for the example.

Comment: @MatthieuM. Atomics appear inside the quote I gave you, yes. I'm skeptical of your reasoning because IIRC the intent of the wording is to warn about the evils of an asynchronous handler (and IIRC as well the wording was here before the abstract machine dealt with threads -- minus atomic types of course). The variable being `thread_local` would not protect against that. Since the result is *not* implementation-defined behaviour but the read of an unspecified value I think your answer would benefit greatly if we had the guarantees that make it work on e.g. Posix.

Comment: I also overlooked it but formally the type `CHandlerType` needs to be a function with C linkage. (This could be `extern "C" typedef void (*CHandlerType)(int);` I think but not at class scope). Similarly `handle_signal` needs to have C linkage.

Comment: @LucDanton: Regarding asynchronous handler: the variable being thread-local avoids synchronizations issues altogether, even on machines where `std::function<...>` is too big to be made atomic, so I really don't understand the possible issues you want to call my attention to (I am sorry for being dumb...) Regarding linkage, I have no idea, linker stuff is generally outside my comfort zone.

Comment: Suppose the signal handler is called midway while `SignalHandler` is being written to. It's not guaranteed to be in any particular state while inside the signal handler because it's not of type `volatile std::sig_atomic_t` or one of the atomic type (which all avoid that because there's no 'midway' when updating variables of such types). No other threads needed. At least that's what I believe the intent of the wording is; in any case it's pretty much explicit that no, you can't read a global `std::function` from a signal handler. (I urge you to read the wording again if necessary.)

Comment: @LucDanton: Damned, I finally understand (I am dense sometimes...). You are right that atomicity is necessary for the global, otherwise all bets are off. I am not too worried for traditional Linux envs, but it is indeed an assumption worth mentionning.

Comment: @LucDanton: Especially since it depends on the particular implementation of `std::function`, though I think an alternative implementation is always possible (using a `std::atomic<void(*)(int)>` as a base for `function`). Thanks for being thorough!

Answer (score 13):

This is indeed a good question. Let's figure out what is going before blaming C++ though. Just think about how lambdas are implemented.

The most simple lambda is when no data is captured. If that is the case, its underlying type becomes a simple plain function. For example, a lambda like this:

```
[] (int p0) {}
```

will be an equivalent of a simple function:

```
void foo(int p0)
{
}
```

That actually perfectly works in case you want that lambda to become a function pointer. For example:

```
#include <string>
#include <csignal>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int ret;
    signal(SIGINT, [](int signal) {
            std::cout << "Got signal " << signal << std::endl;
        });
    std::cin >> ret;
    return ret;
}
```

So far so good. But now you want to associate some data with your signal handler (by the way, the code above is undefined behavior as [you can only execute signal-safe code inside a signal handler](http://lazarenko.me/2013/01/15/how-not-to-write-a-signal-handler/)). So you want a lambda like:

```
#include <string>
#include <csignal>
#include <iostream>

struct handler_context {
    std::string code;
    std::string desc;
};

int main()
{
    int ret;
    handler_context ctx({ "SIGINT", "Interrupt" });
    signal(SIGINT, [&](int signal) {
            std::cout << "Got signal " << signal
                      << " (" << ctx.code << ": " << ctx.desc
                      << ")\n" << std::flush;
        });
    std::cin >> ret;
    return ret;
}
```

Let's forget for a moment about a syntactic sugar of C++ lambdas. It is no secret that you can "mimic" lambda even in C or assembler. So how would that look, actually? "Lambda" in C-style could look like this (this is still C++):

```
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

/*
 * This is a context associated with our lambda function.
 * Some dummy variables, for the sake of example.
 */
struct lambda_captures {
    int v0;
    int v1;
};

static int lambda_func(int p0, void *ctx) // <-- This is our lambda "function".
{
    lambda_captures *captures = (lambda_captures *)ctx;
    std::cout << "Got " << p0 << " (ctx: "
              << captures->v0 << ", " << captures->v1
              << ")\n" << std::flush;
    return 0;
}

// Below is an example of API function provided to the user that can
// invoke a callback supplied by the user.
static void some_api_function(int (*callback)(int p, void *data), void *data)
{
    callback(12345, data);
    callback(98765, data);
}

int main()
{
    lambda_captures captures;
    captures.v0 = 1986;
    captures.v1 = 2012;

    some_api_function(lambda_func, (void *)&captures);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Above is a C style, C++ tends to pass "context" as "this", which is always an implicit first argument. If our API supported passing "data" as first argument, we could apply pointer to member conversion (PMF) and write something like this:

```
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

struct some_class {
    int v0;
    int v1;

    int func(int p0)
    {
        std::cout << "Got " << p0 << " (ctx: "
                  << v0 << ", " << v1
                  << ")\n" << std::flush;
        return p0;
    }
};

static void some_api_function(int (*callback)(void *data, int p), void *data)
{
    callback(data, 12345);
    callback(data, 98765);
}

int main()
{
    typedef int (*mpf_type)(void *, int);

    some_class clazz({ 1986, 2012 }); // <- Note a bit of a Java style :-)
    some_api_function((mpf_type)&some_class::func, (void *)&clazz);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

In the above two examples, note that "data" is always passed around. This is very important. If the API that is supposed to invoke your callback does not accept a "void *" pointer that is passed back to your callback somehow, there is no way you can associate any context with the callback. The only exception is global data. For example, this API is bad:

```
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

struct lambda_captures {
    int v0;
    int v1;
};

static int lambda_func(int p0)
{
/*
    // WHERE DO WE GET OUR "lambda_captures" OBJECT FROM????
    lambda_captures *captures = (lambda_captures *)ctx;
    std::cout << "Got " << p0 << " (ctx: "
              << captures->v0 << ", " << captures->v1
              << ")\n" << std::flush;
*/
    return 0;
}

// Below is an example of API function provided to the user that can
// invoke a callback supplied by the user.
static void some_api_function(int (*callback)(int p))
{
    callback(12345);
    callback(98765);
}

int main()
{
    lambda_captures captures;
    captures.v0 = 1986;
    captures.v1 = 2012;

    some_api_function(lambda_func /* How do we pass a context??? */);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

That being said, an old signal API is exactly like that. The only way to work around the problem is to actually put your "context" into a global scope. Then signal handler function can access it because the address is well known, for example:

```
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

struct lambda_captures {
    int v0;
    int v1;
};

lambda_captures captures({ 1986, 2012 }); // Whoa-la!!!

static int lambda_func(int p0)
{
    std::cout << "Got " << p0 << " (ctx: "
              << captures.v0 << ", " << captures.v1
              << ")\n" << std::flush;
    return 0;
}

// Below is an example of API function provided to the user that can
// invoke a callback supplied by the user.
static void some_api_function(int (*callback)(int p))
{
    callback(12345);
    callback(98765);
}

int main()
{
    some_api_function(lambda_func);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

This is what people have to deal with. Not only in case with signals API. This applies to other things as well. For example, interrupt handler processing. But that low-level programming where you have to deal with hardware. Of course, providing this sort of API in the user-space was not the best idea. And I will mention it again - there is only a small set of things you can do in a signal handler. You can only call [async-signal-safe functions](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/seccode/SIG30-C.+Call+only+asynchronous-safe+functions+within+signal+handlers).

Of course, old API is not going away anytime soon because it is actually a POSIX standard. However, developers recognize the problem and there are better ways to handle signals. In Linux, for example, you can use [`eventfd`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/eventfd.2.html) to install a signal handler, associate it with arbitrary context and do whatever you want in the callback function.

At any rate, let's get back to the lambda you were playing with. The problem is not with C++, but with signals API that leaves no way for you to pass a context except using a global variable. That being said, it works with lambdas too:

```
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <csignal>
#include <iostream>

struct some_data {
    std::string code;
    std::string desc;
};

static some_data data({ "SIGING", "Interrupt" });

int main()
{
    signal(SIGINT, [](int signal) {
            std::cout << "Got " << signal << " (" << data.code << ", "
                      << data.desc << ")\n" << std::flush;
        });
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Therefore, there is no shame in what C++ is doing here as it does a right thing.

Comment: Note that using a (stateless) lambda is not formally well-defined because the conversion yields a pointer to function with unspecified linkage, whereas we need C linkage. I also direct you to [my other comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10816107/anonymous-function-c#comment14079603_10816266).

Answer (score 0):

You cannot easily create a new static function in runtime, some JIT compilers libs are able to do this. 
If you need only a reasonable number of pointers, you can create some pool of static functions by specializing a template.

So easiest way is to wrap C++ Functors by a static function. The problem here is that there is no something like user data parameter. There is only one parameter, that is a number of signal. Since there are only 64 signals, you can create a static array of `std::function< void(int) >` and call each depending on signal number. Some simple example:

```
typedef std::function< void(int) > SignalFunc;

static std::array< SignalFunc, 64 > signalsFunc;

static void cHandler(int nSig)
{
    signalsFunc.at(nSig)(nSig);
}

SignalFunc RegisterSystemSignal( int sig, SignalFunc func )
{
    if( signal( sig, func ? &cHandler : (sighandler_t)SIG_DFL ) != SIG_ERR )
    { 
        func.swap( signalsFunc.at( sig ) );
        return func;
    }
    throw some_error();
}
```

So now you can do that:

```
RegisterSystemSignal(SIGFPE, [&](int nSig)->void{handler(nSig,data);});
```

There is also a `sigaction` witch have more features.